# Parsing xml document

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I have a question regarding dom selectors. This is a part of an xml file I am trying to parse.

```
<title>LASTorder "Reindeer"</title>
<enclosure length="23152990" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" url="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=58822081"/>
```

When I do a query

```
getElementsByTagName('title').childnnodes[0].nodevalue
```

it returns me the content of the title tag.

What query should I make to get the url value inside enclosure ?

```
getElementsByTagName('enclosure').childnnodes[2].nodevalue
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element hasn't got any child nodes, it only has attributes.

```
element.getAttribute('name_of_attribute');
```